# Can I programmatically create a new node revision, without the new revision becoming the "current" one?

Tags: 7, nodes

Whenever my feeds import finds a new version of an existing piece of content, it creates a new revision of this node instead of overwriting data.

Normally the new revision becomes the "current" one right away. I would like the currently displayed revision however to remain the same, and let a moderator decide later if the new one should be published.

Comment: Have you tried using Workbench Moderation, Workflow, or any of the modules that do the same thing?

Comment: I haven't. I initially assumed that because I create the node in code, they didn't apply. Perhaps that's not the case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A standard Drupal install does not allow you to create a "Pending" revision.  You have two options:

1. Programatically create a new revision but programatically revert back to the original revision (which creates an even newer revision, but it has the original content)
2. (Recommended) Use Workbench Moderation, Revisioning or Workflow which are well thought-out solutions for version control and/or access control.

For option 1:
You can add this code as a new Rule or use it in a new module

```
<?php
  // Programatically load the existing revision and save it
  // Taken from http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7
  // Load the revision
  $original_revision = node_load($nid);
  $original_revision->revision = 1;
  $original_revision->log = t('Copy of the revision from %date.', array('%date' => format_date($original_revision->revision_timestamp)));

  $new_revision = node_load($nid);
  // Make any changes to the new revision here...
  $new_revision->revision = 1;
  $new_revision->log = t('Summarize your changes here');

  // Save the new revision first
  node_save($new_revision);

  // Save the original one again so that it is still the current revision
  node_save($original_revision);

  watchdog('content', '@type: reverted %title revision %revision.', array('@type' => $node_revision->type, '%title' => $node_revision->title, '%revision' => $node_revision->vid));
  drupal_set_message(t('@type %title was saved with a new revision, but reverting to original revision from %revision-date.', array('@type' => node_type_get_name($node_revision), '%title' => $node_revision->title, '%revision-date' => format_date($node_revision->revision_timestamp))));
  drupal_goto('node/' . $node_revision->nid . '/revisions');
?>
```

For option 2:
I would recommend Workbench over Revisioning or Workflow, but each is different depending on your needs.  Workbench is kind of the successor to Revisioning, and Workflow is a lot more than just version control, so it may or may not be a good fit for your needs.

Here's a [quick breakdown](https://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/drupal-voices/bec-white-on-the-workbench-module) on the differences between Workbench and Workflow.

Comment: The first option would be great, but how do I make the revert?

Comment: Added the code for option 1, but really option 2 is probably your best bet because it adds functionality for handling which version is current, instead of just duplicating the original over and over again

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Where to write in hook_form_alter ?

Comment: link fixed.  @IcecreamJelly, try hook_node_update.

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess, but I would give the Workbench Moderation sub-module in the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module a shot.  I have found this much easier to set up than [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow).

The fact that you are creating nodes in code shouldn't matter, as long as the `node_save()` runs as a user with the proper settings for the content type (the moderation states are handled with the node API).  This may mean, though, that you need to do some session shenanigans to get things done as the proper user when Feeds runs.

Comment: +1 workbench moderation is a superb module I've been using it for quite a while now