# How to update a content type node after node_submit?

Tags: 6, forms

I am in D6 and need to modify a table entry of a content type field (**content_field_p_fieldname**) after node submit  . What i done is wrote a **hook_form_alter** and written a code to update  in it . This works fine , but problem is : because of node revision works everytime on node edit it creates a revision and creates a new table entry ,and i can update the **second last** entry only .
I found out the cause as  **`'Node is creating revision after hook_form_alter'`** . Any solution on how to i update after node creating the revision , I tried **`hook_node_insert`** but with no luck .

```
/*
 * implementation of hook_form_alter
 */
function module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if (isset($form['#node']) && isset($form_id)){            
        $node = $form['#node'];
        if (isset($form_id)){
            if($form_id == 'p1_request_node_form' || $form_id == 'p2_request_node_form' ) {
                   $form['#submit'][] = 'auto_ip_submit';                                
            }
            else if($form_id == 'ip_range_node_form'){
                    $form['#submit'][] = 'ip_range_submit';
        }
    } 
 }
```

}

and in

```
     function auto_ip_submit(&$form, $form_state) {   
        // stuff to update the table field data
      }
```

But this works only after the revision of node .

Comment: May be the first answer can help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-node-revision-without-the-new-revision-beco

Comment: It does not provide where to write the code , in form_alter ?

Comment: That's is possible but only if you have the nodeid available so you can set the node elements good before saving and editing.

Comment: @Justme didint get you